# Ubuntu is very slow after a few years

Tags: startup, performance

I installed ubuntu a few years ago. In the first days it was very fast compared to windows. However it goes slower by time. It takes more than 1 minute to see the desktop. Chrome takes around 30 seconds for cold start. Atom editor is also same. Also it would take around 4-5 seconds for ubuntu to shut down. Now it takes around 15 seconds. Sometimes it doesn't shutdown at all. It just shows the closing screen and stays in that state indefinitely.

It seems that the new Windows 10 is much more faster than ubuntu. How can I speed up my ubuntu? And why ubuntu isn't faster than windows anymore? I think linux should also use some kind of hibernation like windows do.

Edit: my cpu is intel i7 2.2 GHz. It has turbo mode but afaik linux cannot use that mode. I have 8 GB ram. So it is not due to my hardware.

Comment: Linux will use turbo mode in an i7 processor. Please give examples or evidence why you think it isn't.

Comment: Sometimes I run a dummy code to see how much cpu frequency will increase and it always stays at 2.2 GHz. Never seen it more than that.

Comment: Which frequency driver and scaling governor do you use? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor'.

Comment: intel_pstate and powersave

Comment: How to change it to something other than powersave?

Comment: You don't need to change away from powersave, it is similar to ondemand for the acpi-cpufreq scaling driver. However, to answer your question (as su): `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "performance" > $file; done` If you do not get turbo frequencies, then something is limiting it, either a BIOS setting, or system setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not upgraded this computer in several years I believe Your best option to improve boot performance would be to backup your system data, and perform a compleat system upgrade to the current “[Long Term Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)” Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. If indeed your computers has an Intel i7 processor and 8Gb of ram you should be seeing some pretty spectacular performance results.

Comment: I upgraded to 15.04 recently. I regularly update and upgrade

Comment: If you prefer speed and stability I suggest you go with LTS, and instead of upgrading try a clean install. Things change from release to release, unused libraries and systems settings, better hardware drivers, configuration. Upgrading has a tendency to compound system problems. A clean install might give you better results.

It would easer to judge if you included better system information.

Comment: That is your propagative, do what gives you best results. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first address your Shutdown Problem. Sometimes my system didn't used to shutdown so i tried to mess with my acpi properties. Here's a link to it
[Ubuntu doesn't shutdown properly or hangs at shutdown?](http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.in/2011/11/solved-ubuntu-doesnt-shutdown-properly.html)

Now after you have sorted out your shutdown thing. Let's move to your next problem. A system may get slow after sometime because of the softwares installed on it. Install `bootchart`

```
 sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After installing this just reboot your system and look in `/var/log/bootchart` to check for problems